# How to loop specific MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, symbols

I'm currently making a platform game in Flash CS6 using ActionScript 3. I've managed to setup basic sprites into a single symbol/object, using different frames.

Each sprite/action is itself a different symbol also (for example, there are 5 or so run to the right frames, so I merged them into a separate symbol. That symbol was then copied into the `player` symbol (or the main symbol).

I've managed to get my code to run the specific symbol/frames using the `gotoAndPlay()` command, however my problem is that even though I have a `stop();` action at the end of the loop, it continues onto the next frame.

In this case, it is carrying on to run the first frame of the 'runLeft' animation, before reverting back to the correct 'runRight' animation. However it then keep switching between the two and flickering until I let go of the key.

Say I have a two run animations for both directions, both 5 frames long (1a, 2a, 1b etc). When I press the right arrow key, it will run frames;

```
1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, 1e
```

However, at `1e`, I have a `stop();` command, in theory thinking that since the case is still active it will loop back to the start. Instead, it does this;

`1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, 1e, 2a, 1a, 2a, 1a`.....so on so forth until I release the key. If I were to hold the left arrow key, it would go on to play the first frame of 'animation 3' (the next animation after it).

Here is the code I'm using, but I can't really see it being an issue with the `DocumentMain.as` code, but more of an issue with the symbol(s) themselves?

KeyDown(pressed) handler function;

```
switch(e.keyCode)
{
    case 37:    //Left Arrow
        _vx = -5;
        _player.gotoAndPlay("runLeft");
        break;

    case 38:    //Up Arrow
        _vy = -27;
        break;

    case 39:    //Right Arrow
        _vx = 5;
        _player.gotoAndPlay("runRight");
        break;

    default:
}
```

And the KeyUP handler function;

```
switch(e.keyCode)
{
    case 37:    //Left Arrow                
        _vx = 0;
        _player.gotoAndPlay("standLeft");
        break;

    case 39:    //Right Arrow
        _player.gotoAndPlay("standRight");
        _vx = 0;
        break;

    default:
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here:

1. The down key will get called repeatedly after a few seconds, so it will continually tell the movieClip to gotoAndPlay a certain frame, hence why you're getting the repeated **1a, 2a, 1a...etc** at the end of your animation sequence. You need to only call the gotoAndPlay once on keyDown, i.e. perhaps use a boolean to track that:

   ```
   case 37:    //Left Arrow keydown
       _vx = -5;
       if (!isLeft) {
           isLeft = true;
           _player.gotoAndPlay("runLeft");
       }
       break;


   case 37:    //Left Arrow keyup
       _vx = 0;
       isLeft = false;
       _player.gotoAndPlay("standLeft");
       break;
   ```
2. Instead of using stop(); on the movieClip frame, use i.e. gotoAndPlay('1a') so the animation will loop itself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I managed to fix it now your help helped a lot :)

Just one question - I'm trying to make the game run the 'Jump' animation (facing right) at which point it then runs the default 'Stand still' animation (facing right also). However I cannot figure out how to send it to that animation.

As before, the animations are symbols within the 'Player' symbol. I've tried to use `gotoAndPlay("standRight", "Player");` but it doesn't recognize Player as the directory of where the other animation is, but it doesnt. Is there a different command to go between symbols?

Comment: Glad that worked. Unfortunately you can't tell gotoAndPlay to play 2 things at once. If I understood you correctly you can make the character face left/right whilst playing the jumping animation very easily. Set up your animation movieClip with the character facing right or left only, i.e. jump animation facing right, walk animation facing right...etc. The trick is to change the xScale to -1 so that the animation movieClip is flipped 180 degrees horizontally, as if it was facing left.

Comment: Thanks :) I've got it flipped/jumping the right way. However when the player lands, I can't figure out how to make the character stand facing the same way (if not moving) or run the same way. The player just...disappears until a key is pressed, but I'd prefer the character to stand then run (better transition) :/

Comment: @NeoKuro unforutnately I need more information to assist you. What code did you use to handle the jumping animation and after it lands. Maybe start another thread with the code you are using :)

Comment: Sorry tried solving it myself for a bit (and cba to do it past few days haha) But I finally solved it, using the previous solution with flipping it. Thanks a bunch :)